# Results page is not holding query when paginating

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and need a little help.

I have a website which has courses which can be refinded my month, day of week etc..

The filter functions work perfectly but when I paginate, it removes all of the query. It's obvious to see why in the paste bin on line 90, but I cannot think of the way to keep it.

Can anyone help?

https://pastebin.com/8MFEkFjn

My Paginator has this:

```
@include('frontend.partials.pagination', ['paginator' => $courses->appends(Input::only('category_parent', 'course_week', 'start_date', 'category_child', 'tutor', 'day', 'time_of_day', 'order_by', 'keyword'))])
```

You can see the live website with a filter here:

http://www.bristolfolkhouse.co.uk/results?keyword=&category_parent=&course_week=&month=03&category_child=&day=&time_of_day=&tutor=

Thanks.

Paolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`appends()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) method to keep request data, for example:

```
{{ $collection->appends([
    'keyword' => request('keyword'),
    'category_parent' => request('category_parent')
    ....
])->render() }}
```

Comment: I actually have this in place, but doesn't seem to be effecting it:

@include('frontend.partials.pagination', ['paginator' => $courses->appends(Input::only('category_parent', 'course_week', 'start_date', 'category_child', 'tutor', 'day', 'time_of_day', 'order_by', 'keyword'))])

Comment: @PaoloResteghini you can look at HTML generated by this code to understand does it work or not.

Comment: It doesn't work - That's my problem. All of the values are blank. I tried without a custom pagination also and still nothing: 

{{ $courses->appends(Input::only('category_parent', 'course_week', 'start_date', 'category_child', 'tutor', 'day', 'time_of_day', 'order_by', 'keyword'))->render() }}

Comment: Sorry this did work - I was missing one of the params. Thanks.